# I need to simplify an MS Access SQL Query in order to understand why I am getting data discrepencies in my reports

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Database that I took over from a colleague that is no long with my organization.  One of the Queries is causing me a ton of trouble.  It is a make table query that includes three joins (see code below).

My idea is that it would be easier to use a simplified make table query with blank categories and then use 2 or 3 update queries to fill in the data vs trying to do it all in one fell swoop.

This one giant query is tough to parse when data issues arise, when I could just step through the three update queries.  My issue is that I am having trouble pulling apart the below make table query.

If I could just figure out what to start the base of the table with then it would be easy to fit everything into place.  If someone could suggest the best way to create the table in the first place without adding in the complicated joins that would be ideal.  Thank you in advance!

```
SELECT DISTINCT '' AS [Transaction for the record]
    ,[Current Employee Census] ! [SSN] AS [Subscriber's Social Security Number]
    ,[Current Employee Census] ! [FIRST_NAME] AS [Member's First Name]
    ,[Current Basic Work] ! [MIDDLE_NAME] AS [Member's Middle Initial]
    ,[Current Employee Census] ! [LAST_NAME] AS [Member's Last name]
    ,[Current Basic Work] ! [ADDRESS_LN1] AS [Member's Address 1]
    ,[Current Basic Work] ! [ADDRESS_LN2] AS [Member's Address 2]
    ,[Current Basic Work] ! [CITY_NM] AS [Member's City]
    ,[Current Basic Work] ! [STATE_CD] AS [Member's State or Province]
    ,Format([Current Basic Work] ! [ZIP_CD], "00000") AS [Member's Postal Code]
    ,Format([Current Employee Census].DATE_OF_BIRTH, "yyyy-mm-dd") AS [Member's Date of Birth]
    ,"00" AS [Member's Relationship to the Subscriber]
    ,[Current Basic Work].SSN AS [Member's Social Security Number]
    ,[Current Basic Work].PHONE AS [Member's Daytime Phone Number]
    ,[Current HRIS report].[Home Phone] AS [Member's Evening Phone Number]
    ,[Current HRIS report].[Cell Phone] AS [Member's Cell Phone Number]
    ,Format([Current MED BDR].EFFECTIVE_DATE, "yyyy-mm-dd") AS [Member's Effective Date of Coverage]
    ,[Current MED BDR].END_DATE AS [Member's Coverage Expiration Date]
    ,[Current Basic Work].WORK_EMAIL AS [Member's Email Address]
    ,'' AS [Member's Marital Status]
    ,[Current Employee Census].GENDER AS [Member's Gender]
    ,Format([Current Employee Census].EMPLOYER_ID, "000000000") AS [Subscriber's Unique Identifier]
    ,IIf([Current MED BDR].[PERSON_TYPE] = "Retired", "R", "A") AS [Subscriber's Status]
    ,[Current MED BDR].SSN
    ,'' AS Filler
    ,IIf([Current MED BDR].[CARRIER_NAME] = "Company1", "COMPANY1", IIf([Current MED BDR].[CARRIER_NAME] = "Company2", "COMPANY2", IIf([Current MED BDR].[CARRIER_NAME] = "Company3", "COMPANY4", "OPTOUT"))) AS [Carrier Name]
    ,IIf([Current MED BDR].[COVERAGE_NAME] = "Self Only", "EMP", IIf([Current MED BDR].[COVERAGE_NAME] = "Family", "FAM", IIf([Current MED BDR].[COVERAGE_NAME] = "Self + Child(ren)", "ECH", IIf([Current MED BDR].[COVERAGE_NAME] = "Self + Spouse", "ESP", [Current MED BDR].[COVERAGE_NAME])))) AS Coverage
    ,'' AS [Client Attribute 3]
    ,'' AS [Client Attribute 4]
    ,'' AS [Client Attribute 5]
    ,'' AS Filler2
    ,[Current MED BDR].PERSON_TYPE
INTO [Employee Records]
FROM (
    (
        [Current Employee Census] RIGHT JOIN [Current Basic Work] ON [Current Employee Census].SSN = [Current Basic Work].SSN
        ) LEFT JOIN [Current MED BDR] ON [Current Basic Work].SSN = [Current MED BDR].SSN
    )
LEFT JOIN [Current HRIS report] ON [Current Basic Work].SSN = [Current HRIS report].SSN
WHERE (((IIf([Current MED BDR].[CARRIER_NAME] = "Company1", "COMPANY1", IIf([Current MED BDR].[CARRIER_NAME] = "Company2", "COMPANY2", IIf([Current MED BDR].[CARRIER_NAME] = "Company3", "COMPANY4", "OPTOUT")))) <> "COMPANY4"));
```

Comment: When your `FROM` has the format: `t1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1 = t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t2 = t3` then `t2` is your driving table. It could be rewritten as `FROM t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 on t1 = t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t2 = t3` That simplifies it a bit for me. The rest of it seems pretty straight forward though.

Comment: IT starts with `Current Basic Work`, then pulls in `current employee census`, then adds `current med bdr` , finally `current hris report`.  the where clause is a bit strange as it translates company 3 to company4 and then excludes it.  and items flagged as optout remain.  I think access has a [switch](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php) function which might make this easier to read similar to SQL Case statements.  Replace nested iif's with a switch perhaps.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to figure out which table includes all records from that table, and then which tables just add the missing data.